# The privileges section of the help center should mention the "be able to cast votes on a moderator election" privilege at 150 points

Tags: feature-request, help-center, privileges, moderator-election

I only got to know about this requirement when I visited [the election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) and even the ([Caucus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1973/caucus) and [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent) badges do not have the reputation written).

Also, the privilege at 3000 reputation points, "Stand in the Nomination in a moderator election" should be mentioned.

In fact, the entire Stack Overflow portion of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di/160292#160292) should be mentioned in the [privileges article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: If you're going to do that, you might as well mention the reputation requirement for standing in the election too.

Comment: I don't know if being is a mod a "privilege". But then again, neither is reviewing..

Comment: @yivi upvoting and downvoting are privileges "cast close and reopen votes" is a privilege so voting for mods should also be a privilege

Comment: @user16714199 I was replying to Chenmunka comment. And my reply was mostly tongue in cheek. I agree with your request, and with Chenmunka's point.

Comment: The canonical for privileges (with the most detailed information) is *[What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di/160292#160292)*. Note that some of the information is in the ***footnotes***.